# How do I convert an IOC country code to country name?

Tags: python, pandas, country-codes, pycountry-convert

I have a pandas dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd

s = pd.DataFrame({'ioc' : ['ESP', 'CYP', 'USA', 'ESP', 'NED']})
```

and I want to return

```py
out = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ioc' : ['ESP', 'CYP', 'USA', 'ESP', 'NED'],
     'countryName' : ['Spain', 'Cyprus', 'United States of America',
                      'Spain', 'Netherlands']})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [List of IOC country codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IOC_country_codes)

```
ioc = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IOC_country_codes')[0]
ioc = ioc.assign(Code=ioc['Code'].str[-3:]).set_index('Code')['National Olympic Committee']

s['countryName'] = s['ioc'].map(ioc)
print(s)

# Output:
   ioc    countryName
0  ESP          Spain
1  CYP         Cyprus
2  USA  United States
3  ESP          Spain
4  NED    Netherlands
```

Answer (score 7):

```
import pycountry

def foo(a):
    country = pycountry.countries.get(alpha_3=a)
    return country.name if country else "NA"
    
s.ioc.apply(foo)
0            Spain
1           Cyprus
2    United States
3            Spain
4               NA
Name: ioc, dtype: object
```

Another option

```
import country_converter as coco
cc = coco.CountryConverter()
cc.convert(names=s.ioc, to='name')
# ['Spain', 'Cyprus', 'United States', 'Spain', 'not found']
```

You can also read data from [country_converter](https://github.com/konstantinstadler/country_converter) repo.

```
import json
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohitsdaniel/country./master/lib/data/masterData.json"
) as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
d = {
    x.get("ioc"): x.get("names")["en"][0]
    for x in data["code"]["ISO2"].values()
    if x.get("ioc")
}
s.ioc.apply(lambda x: d.get(x, "NA"))
0            Spain
1           Cyprus
2    United States
3            Spain
4      Netherlands
Name: ioc, dtype: object
```

Comment: Good enough. Still facing some issues with some IOC (International Olympic Committee) specific codes such as GER (Germany) and NED (Netherlands).